# Datagramchannel not receiving data from wlan0 interface

Tags: java, interface, nio, loopback

I'm trying to implement 3 channels using java nio, and everything works correctly on lo interface. Receiving and sending data works just fine on loopback interface, but when changing to wlan0 it seems that i am unable to receive datagrams. I can send them correctly (verified on wireshark) but dont receive anything as in lo.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Ok, i solved it. It was due to router restrictions, it works as it is supposed. Thanks anyway :)